# Best Strategy for Switching between Multiple States?

Tags: jquery, performance

I currently have three classes: `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Elements only have one of these classes at a time.

My current approach is to simply call the following every time a class change is required:

```
$('#element').addClass('a').removeClass('b c');
```

There are other ways to achieve the same effect - but using property selectors, for instance, may be more expensive in the long run. It is not a tristate cycle, in that I may sometimes need to switch `a` to `b` *or* vice versa. Is my above approach the most efficient strategy performance-wise? If not, what is better, or what terms can I search for to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, unless you are doing this thousands of times at once, I rather doubt the performance of calling `.removeClass('b c')` is going to be even noticeable.  My general rule is to write code with the following priorities in order:

1. Correctness
2. Readability and Maintainability
3. Efficient/Compact
4. Performance

I only every spend any development cycles on performance if I've found a legitimate performance issue and have profiled/measured what is going on enough to know which piece of code needs to be improved and can then measure whether I am indeed actually improving it.

If you have no other classes on the object, then the simplest way is to just set the new class name:

```
 $('#element').attr('class', 'a');
```

If you do have other class names on the object, and you know in advance what those are, then you can do this:

```
 $('#element').attr('class', 'a ' + otherClassNmes);
```

If you don't want to assume any prior knowledge of other class names, then you will need to look for both of the other class names and remove them if present.  You can look at jQuery's code for `.removeClass()` and see exactly what it does.

```
removeClass: function( value ) {
    var classes, elem, cur, clazz, j,
        i = 0,
        len = this.length,
        proceed = arguments.length === 0 || typeof value === "string" && value;

    if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        return this.each(function( j ) {
            jQuery( this ).removeClass( value.call( this, j, this.className ) );
        });
    }
    if ( proceed ) {
        classes = ( value || "" ).match( core_rnotwhite ) || [];

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            elem = this[ i ];
            // This expression is here for better compressibility (see addClass)
            cur = elem.nodeType === 1 && ( elem.className ?
                ( " " + elem.className + " " ).replace( rclass, " " ) :
                ""
            );

            if ( cur ) {
                j = 0;
                while ( (clazz = classes[j++]) ) {
                    // Remove *all* instances
                    while ( cur.indexOf( " " + clazz + " " ) >= 0 ) {
                        cur = cur.replace( " " + clazz + " ", " " );
                    }
                }
                elem.className = value ? jQuery.trim( cur ) : "";
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive alternatives, and for now `.attr('class', 'a')` seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `toggleClass`? If you have only 3 classes you can keep some array with states like this:

```
var states = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  c: false
}

function toggle(el, state) { 
    var $el = $(el);
    for( var class in state)
        $el.toggleClass(class, state[class]);
}

toggle( someEl, states);
```

It can be done as jQuery plugin as well.
Ofcourse it is not the fastest way, but quite readable I think. For efficiency you can use native `el.className` (when you have only 3 classes it might be the best way).

Comment: +1 This is definitely a readable solution, and it didn't at all occur to me to put the classes in an array and cycle through them. Ideally, though, there would be an intuitive and immediate way to require that an element only has one class at a time. It appears that @jfriend00's `attr('class','a')` is what I was looking for.